# Get latest record for each category in one request | Yii2

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I have category (Category model).

Each category has child categories (via Category model field `parent_id`).

Each child category has products (via Product field `category_id`).

I need to get the latest added product for each parent category. And ideally it should take one request. Or as less requests as possible.

---

I think it should work via relation and looks something like the following:

```
$areas = Category::find()
    ->parent()
    ->published()
    ->orderBy('position ASC')
    ->with('latestProduct')
    ->limit(8)
    ->asArray()
    ->all();

public function getLatestProduct()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Product::className(), ['category_id' => 'id'])
        ->viaTable('category', ['parent_id' => 'id'])
            ->published()
            ->with('firstImage')
            ->orderBy('date_create DESC');
}
```

This piece of code doesn't work as expected. Is it written correctly and how I should implement this type of task?

Comment: you can add time stamp column in your database for every product you add, by using timestamp you can write query to get results

Comment: if you have relation`category_table with  product_table  and firstImage` then you can use like `product.firstImage` then you can add condition with that.

Answer (score -1):

In your `Category` model, you can do something like this.

```
public function latestProducts()
{
    return Product::find()->where(['category_id' => $this->id])->published()->with('firstImage')->orderBy('date_create DESC')->all();
}
```

In your view while looping for each category, call this function as shown below.

```
$category->latestProducts(); // where $category is the current category in loop
```

Comment: And then we have as many requests as categories in the loop. That's not appropriate solution. I want to do it in the least possible number of requests.

Comment: Well, you didn't mention that in your original question so downvoting a technically correct answer is a bit harsh for someone who is seeking help.

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. I'll remove downvote when 12 hours restriction is gone. I put it accidently. Any ideas on my task?

Comment: What exactly is the error or data you're getting when you run your code?